# For $x$ and $\lambda$ complex, if $|x| \gt \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4} + |\lambda|}$ then $|x^2+\lambda| \gt |x| +1$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

> Define $f(z) = z \ ^ 2 + \lambda$ and $V = \left\{x \in \Bbb C : |x| \gt \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4} + |\lambda|} \right\}$, for some $\lambda \in \Bbb C$.
>   Then, if $x \in V$ then $|f(x)| \gt |x| +1$.

I tried the following :

Let $x\in V$ then $|f(x)| = |x \  ^ 2 +\lambda | \ge |x |  \ ^ 2 - | \lambda| \gt (\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4} + |\lambda|}) \  ^ 2 - |\lambda| = 1.5 + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4} + |\lambda|} $.

But this doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Please no `\dfrac` where they are not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (2017-10-24) *Amusing* downvote, purely for mathematical reasons, I am sure...

One wants to show that, for every real number $u$, if $u>\frac12+\sqrt{\frac54+b}$ for some $b\geqslant0$, then $u^2-b>u+1$.

But the conclusion $u^2-b>u+1$ is equivalent to $u^2-u+\frac14>\frac54+b$, that is, $\left(u-\frac12\right)^2>\frac54+b$, and since the hypothesis $u>\frac12+\sqrt{\frac54+b}$ ensures that $\left(u-\frac12\right)^2>\frac54+b$, we are done.

Comment: But this is over the complex plane, not the reals

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Indeed, but surely you noted that the only relevant quantities to solve the question, namely, $|x|$, $|\lambda|$, $|x|+1$ and $|x|^2-|\lambda|$, are all real valued.

Comment: Ahh, I see.${}{}$

Comment: @Did you wrote "u>..." then $u \ ^ 2 -b \gt u+1$ , doesnt it $|u \ ^ 2 +b| > .. $  ?

Comment: @Did btw i did not downvoted the post.. but maybe someone saw a mistake

Comment: @Liad Indeed this is what one could think, naïvely, but be sure that the downvote is not due to somebody seeing a mistake...

Comment: Re the maths, you showed yourself in your question that if $$|x |^2 - | \lambda| \gt|x|+1$$ then we are done. Thus, this is the step I prove.

Comment: Huh. ok let me reread this.

Comment: nice! thanks @Did