# bounded julia set $f(z)=z^2 + c$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

prove that $|f(z)|>|z|+1$ where $z\in V$ and
$V=\left\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|> \frac 1 2 + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4} +|c|}\,\right\}$ and $f(z)=z^2+c$ and $c\in \Bbb C$

I can't seem to get anywhere needing to prove $|z^2+c|>|z|+1$ over $V$.
I tried putting in $z= a+bi$ , $c = p + qi$ but it just gets complicated.

this is later used to prove that the julia set of $f$ is bounded.

any help would be great. thanks!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2488001/115115

Comment: It's the same question, but the answer I got here is better so please don't delete it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root in the definition of $V$ is the solution of the quadratic equation 
$$
(r-\frac12)^2-\frac54-|c|=r^2-r-1-|c|=0
$$
with the other root being negative. For $|z|>r$ we are on the rising branch of the parabola and  you get thus
$$
|z|^2-|z|-1-|c|> 0
$$
and thus
$$
|f(z)|\ge |z|^2-|c|> |z|+1
$$

---

Or put another way
\begin{align}
|f(z)|-|z|-1&\ge|z|^2-|z|-1-|c|\\
&=(|z|^2-|z|-1-|c|)-(r^2-r-1-|c|)\\
&=(|z|-r)(|z|+r-1)> 0
\end{align}
as $r>1$ and $|z|>r$

Comment: thank you! I should have started with the set V. would you please explain the "other way" you put it? how do you go from the first line to the second? what is r? you just subtracted something yet said it's equal to the first line. thanks!

Comment: $r$ is the root of the polynomial. This is valid for all polynomials and related to the Horner-Ruffini rule. If $p(r)=0$ then $p(x)=p(x)-p(r)=(x-r)q(x,r)$ where $q$ is some other polynomial obtained by polynomial division.